# Finding Chi^2 of a Non-Linear Fit Model

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, fitting, nonlinear

**Question:**

I have some data, with a `y=Ae^(-kt)` model applied (It's a radioactive decay), thanks to answers on another question, the model is applied and returns the relevant numbers, but I need the value for the Chi^2 as a quantification for goodness of fit. Can anyone help me with how to about this? I've used PearsonChiSquaredFit in the example below.

**Minimalised Example:**

```
dataHist5 = {{Around[16.5, 1.5], 
   Around[77.8, 8.8]}, {Around[34.5, 1.5], 
   Around[60.5, 8.0]}, {Around[52.5, 1.5], 
   Around[63.8, 8.0]}, {Around[106.5, 1.5], 
   Around[42.4, 6.5]}, {Around[124.5, 1.5], 
   Around[41.7, 6.5]}, {Around[142.5, 1.5], 
   Around[14.6, 3.8]}, {Around[160.5, 1.5], 
   Around[33.9, 5.8]}, {Around[178.5, 1.5], 
   Around[29.4, 5.4]}}}
data = Transpose[{dataHist5[[All, 1, 1]], dataHist5[[All, 2, 1]]}];
ListLogPlot[data]

logData = data;
logData[[All, 2]] = Log[data[[All, 2]]]/data[[All, 1]];
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[logData, loga/t - k, {loga, k}, t];
nlm["BestFitParameters"]

Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[Exp[t nlm[t]], {t, 1, 700}]]
ListPlot[Transpose[{logData[[All, 1]], nlm["FitResiduals"]}], 
 PlotRange -> All]

logData = data;
logData[[All, 2]] = Log[data[[All, 2]]]/data[[All, 1]];
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[logData, 
   loga/t - Log[2]/halfLife, {loga, halfLife}, t];
nlm["ParameterTable"]
PearsonChiSquareTest[logData, nlm]
```

**This returns:**

```
PearsonChiSquareTest::rctnlndst: The argument 

FittedModel[-0.00676871+4.44614/t] at position 2 should be a valid distribution or a rectangular array of real numbers with length greater than the dimension of the array. The dimensionality of the arguments at positions 1 and 2 must match. {{16.5, 0.263887}, {34.5,
0.118917}, {52.5, 0.0791572}, {106.5, 
   0.0351845}, {124.5, 0.0299639}, {142.5, 0.0188142}, {160.5, 
   0.0219527}, {178.5, 0.0189411}, {196.5, 0.0178705}, {214.5, 
   0.0159942}, {232.5, 0.0147837}, {250.5, 0.0122477}, {268.5, 
   0.00543246}, {286.5, 0.00647923}, {322.5, 0.00624776}, {340.5, 
   0.00441726}, {358.5, 0.00668869}, {376.5, 0.00700945}, {394.5, 
   0.00668963}, {466.5, -0.00109502}, {484.5, 0.00162736}, {520.5, 
   0.00430492}, {538.5, 0.00262022}, {646.5, 
   0.00121958}, {682.5, -0.000748462}}, \!\(\* TagBox[ RowBox[{"FittedModel", "[",  TagBox[ PanelBox[ TagBox[ RowBox[{ RowBox[{"-", "0.00676871191449669`"}], "+",  FractionBox["4.4461438703116665`", "t"]}], Short[#, 2]& ], FrameMargins->5], Editable -> False], "]"}], InterpretTemplate[
    FittedModel[{
      "Nonlinear", {$CellContext`loga -> 4.4461438703116665`, \ $CellContext`halfLife -> 102.40459179174366`}, ...
```

**Exponential Decay Graph of the expanded data set:**
[image: Expanded data set e^-x graph]

**EDIT - R^2:**
I managed to find this for finding R^2. Ideally I would like to be able to return something like this for Chi^2

```
Grid[Transpose[{#, nlm[#]} &[{"AdjustedRSquared", "AIC", "BIC", 
    "RSquared"}]], Alignment -> Left]
```

For me this returns:
`R^2 = 0.998555`
Though that does look a bit high for the fit above.

**EDIT - Real Data:**
Posting real data as requested:

```
dataHist5 = {{Around[16.5, 1.5], Around[77.8, 8.8]}, {Around[34.5, 1.5], 
   Around[60.5, 8.0]}, {Around[52.5, 1.5], 
   Around[63.8, 8.0]}, {Around[106.5, 1.5], 
   Around[42.4, 6.5]}, {Around[124.5, 1.5], 
   Around[41.7, 6.5]}, {Around[142.5, 1.5], 
   Around[14.6, 3.8]}, {Around[160.5, 1.5], 
   Around[33.9, 5.8]}, {Around[178.5, 1.5], 
   Around[29.4, 5.4]}, {Around[196.5, 1.5], 
   Around[33.5, 5.8]}, {Around[214.5, 1.5], 
   Around[30.9, 5.6]}, {Around[232.5, 1.5], 
   Around[31.1, 5.8]}, {Around[250.5, 1.5], 
   Around[21.5, 4.6]}, {Around[268.5, 1.5], 
   Around[4.3, 2.1]}, {Around[286.5, 1.5], 
   Around[6.4, 2.5]}, {Around[322.5, 1.5], 
   Around[7.5, 2.7]}, {Around[340.5, 1.5], 
   Around[4.5, 2.1]}, {Around[358.5, 1.5], 
   Around[11., 3.3]}, {Around[376.5, 1.5], 
   Around[14.0, 3.7]}, {Around[394.5, 1.5], 
   Around[14.0, 3.7]}, {Around[466.5, 1.5], 
   Around[0.6, 0.7]}, {Around[502.5, 1.5], 
   Around[2.2, 1.5]}, {Around[520.5, 1.5], 
   Around[9.4, 3.1]}, {Around[538.5, 1.5], 
   Around[4.1, 2.0]}, {Around[646.5, 1.5], 
   Around[2.2, 1.5]}, {Around[682.5, 1.5], Around[0.6, 0.7]}}
```

**EDIT - Recreating Answer**

```
Show[ListPlot[dataHist5], Plot[fit[x], {x, 0, 800}, PlotRange -> All]]
fit["ANOVATableSumsOfSquares"][[2]] (*chi^2*)
fit["ANOVATableMeanSquares"][[2]] (*chi^2/dof*)

uncertainties = dataHist5[[All, 2, 2]];

fit = NonlinearModelFit[rawDataHist5, A*Exp[-k*t], {A, k}, t, 
   Weights -> 1/uncertainties^2];
```

Produces: Chi^2 = 90.68, Chi^2/DOF = 3.94. Which slightly differs from the quoted results of 90.75, 3.95 respectively. I'm not too sure why. The data isn't great so 3.95 seems like a realistic figure.

Comment: Is there some reason for needing a "Chi^2" statistic?  The standard summary statistic (in most applied fields) is the root mean square error (RMSE) for assessing predictions and standard errors (or confidence intervals) for the regression parameters.

Comment: It was just suggested to me as a measure for goodness of fit, and matches previous times I've used it. But I am open to suggestions, how would I go about getting the RMSE in MMa?
The ultimate goal is to get a figure for the half life, it's uncertainty, and a measure for how good the fit from the model was. It was also suggested from cross-validated that I try a Poisson GLM with log link model as opposed to standard nonlinearmodel, though I'm out my depth on statistics to know much there

Comment: The suggestion that you use a Poisson GLM was a good one.  But those on CrossValidated assumed from your description that you had counts.  And you need counts (i.e., integers) to use `GeneralizedLinearModelFit`.  As a statistician when I want to do brain surgery, I consult a brain surgeon.  Just a suggestion.

Comment: I think I might be missing the metaphor - is Cross Validated a poor place to obtain statistics advice, I was under the impression it was basically the Stats SE?

Comment: Sorry, my sarcasm was apparently very unclear.  CrossValidated is great.  What I was trying say was the you really ought to consult a statistician when you need statistical help.  (And apparently not knowing that integer counts are required for Poisson regression seems to me a strong indication that you should really do so.)

Comment: Oh yes, you're probably right there. My stats knowledge is 15 years rusty, and since COVID the time I get to invest in this project is in short supply which is a shame, and I don't really know any statisticians, which is why Cross Validated seemed like a good choice. I'm trying to pick stuff up and reread things where I get the chance to. Apologies if I took up your time, I really do appreciate the help all the same

Comment: @JimB I was wondering if you might know, why this version (probably clearer to see below in the answers) returns a much different value to your answer from my initial question ( https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/239832/applying-an-exponential-decay-fit-with-uncertainties )
It's values for t are considerably smaller. I understand your answer used a slightly different method but went to the same ends, is the weighting applied differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
nlm["ANOVATable"]
```

Will give you a summary of some variance metrics, including the Chi^2.

Under the Error row, you'll find

- DF: degrees of freedom: 6
- SS: Chi^2: 0.0000452471...
- MS: Chi^2/dof: 7.54118*10^-6

If you want to extract the value programmatically, use

```
nlm["ANOVATableSumsOfSquares"][[2]]
```

PS:This is documented in the "Details and Options" tab of the [`NonlinearModelFit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html)documentation.

---

**For your real data edit:**

see the following code:

```
rawDataHist5=dataHist5/.{Around[v_,__]:>v}; (*strip away the around's for the fit*)

fit=NonlinearModelFit[rawDataHist5,A*Exp[-k*t],{A,k},t];

Show[ListPlot[dataHist5],Plot[fit[x],{x,0,800},PlotRange->All]]
fit["ANOVATableSumsOfSquares"][[2]] (*chi^2*)
fit["ANOVATableMeanSquares"][[2]] (*chi^2/dof*)
```

Which yields the plot
[image: Fit model with data]

and the χ^2 of 1157.97
and a χ^2/dof of 50.35

However, your data can be weihted according to your uncertainties:

```
uncertainties=dataHist5[[All,2,2]];

fit=NonlinearModelFit[rawDataHist5,A*Exp[-k*t],{A,k},t,Weights->1/uncertainties^2];
```

In this case, the weights will be taken into account by calculating the χ^2 and we get
χ^2 = 90.75
χ^2/dof = 3.95

Comment: Thank you. Why was the pearsonchisquared command not working by the way? I'm getting the result of 0.000125, which seems like a very low figure, suggesting a big overfitting, but it doesn't look that way. And when I've fitted this graph on other things such as python and origin it's returned figures in the `10^2` range (which is still not great), do you know why there might be such a large difference?

Comment: If you look into the documentation for PearsonChiSquareTest, you see that the function does something totally different. Namely, using the Pearson X^2 test of checking for an underlying distribution of given data. Not evaluate the X^2 value for a fit. The X^2 value is only dependent on the fit result, so if origin and python came to the same parameter set, then all values should be the same. Maybe you compared your 'logData' fit with  afit of the real data? If you post the real data this would be easy to show.

Comment: In the case of origin and python it's definitely not log data that's fitted because I haven't written any code that does that yet. I'd like to get the chi^2 of the exponential decay curve on the graph shown, and it's probanly safe to say I'm out my depth mathematica wise. I've included the full real data set as requested.

Comment: I edited the answer accordingly. The weighted answer of 3.95 for the chi^2/dof is realistically looking at your data.

Comment: Yeh, it's not great data is it? Might I ask why the weighting 1/uncertainty^2 is used rather than 1/uncertainty? And whether chi^2 or chi^2/dof is the most relevant metric here?

Comment: I've seen worse. 3.95 isn't great, but not the worst either. Weighting is dependent on what you want to archieve with it. The 1/u you suggested is called statistical weighting. For measured data, instrumental weighting is the de facto standard which is one over the standard deviation and thus 1/u^2. The relevant metric for judging the goodness of fit is chi^2/dof. Its expectation value is n/(n-p) with n the amount of data points and p the number of parameters. For n>>p you thus expect chi^2/dof = 1.

Comment: I see, thank you, that's much clearer. Why does it use 23 as the DOF here, when there are 25 points?
I've recreated your answer (editted the question), it's almost exactly the same, but do you know why there is a slight difference? For example, X^2/dof = 3.94 and X^2 = 90.68

Comment: The degrees of freedom is the number of datapoints minus the number of parameters. Since you have two parameters, A and k, you reach dof=25-2=23. for the discrepancy: I rounded to two decimal digits after the point while giving you the results. I'll check if I did something wrong there when I can.

Comment: Well, I can confirm what I've wrote so far, chi^2=90.7548 and chi^2/dof=3.94586. Maybe you took slightly other datapoints? What is your output of `Around@@@Transpose[{fit["BestFitParameters"][[All,2]],fit["ParameterErrors"]}]`? Mine is `List[Around[87.89476991568526,12.334923681777726],Around[0.0077664529581594425,0.000816278519064779]]`

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I think I was counting t as well as a parameter.
Mine are: 88 +/- 12, and 0.0078 +/- 0.0008 exactly.

Comment: Might it be rounding error based? Maybe different versions of mathematica round to different amounts at high number of significant figures? It's just odd that the difference should be so small

Comment: I do get the same values. Maybe i did not copy the whole dataset the first time. Btw, it's not 88 +/- 12 exactly. Mathematica, behind the scenes, tracks the precision to its fully extend. It just displays a rounded off variant to you. You can force it to show the full precision by utilizing FullForm[]. Also: if you want to, you can accept the answer above.

Comment: That's a nice tip to know. What point does mathematica decide it's close enough to just show '88.' instead of say '87.9' or '87.99'?
Sorry, completely forgot, I'll do that now. Thank you for the answer and help

Comment: Well, it all depends on the uncertainty. Usually when reporting estimates with their error, the rounding is based off the first significant digit of the uncertainty (this what happens with the 0.0078+-...). This has an exception for when the uncertainty starts with the digits 1 or 2. Then the precision is usually extended to two significant digits. At least thats how DIN handles it. Mathematica however, puts this border at digits 1 to 3.5. Why 3.5 instead of 2? I don't know.
Thanks.