# Plot Styling Errors (PlotLabel, PlotTheme, Inset not appearing)

Tags: plotting, graphics, fitting, warning-messages

**Question:**

I'm trying to pull together a graph with labelled axes, a title, and an inset box with information relating to the plot such as the y-intercept (A in this code) and it's uncertainty. However, none of the conditions beyond the initial plot implements, and outputs 3 or 4 pages of errors, but can't see what the error is, even with the description

**Code:**

```
fit = NonlinearModelFit[dataHist5, A*Exp[-k*t], {A, k}, t, 
   Weights -> 1/uncertainties^2];
hLife = Log[2]/Around[k, \[Sigma]k]
seA = Around[A, \[Sigma]A]

halfLife = hLife[[1]] /. fit["BestFitParameters"]
sehalfLife = 
 hLife[[2]] /. fit["BestFitParameters"] /. \[Sigma]k -> 
   fit["ParameterErrors"][[2]]

uncertainties = dataHist5[[All, 2, 2]];

Show[ListPlot[dataHist5], 
 Plot[fit[x], {x, 0, 800}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLabel -> "Decay Curve of Phosphorus-31 by \[Beta]^{+} Emission",
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed", PlotStyle -> Red, 
  LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold}, {0.85, 0.75}], 
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}, 
   FrameLabel -> {"Time /s", 
     "Counts Recorded in the Previous 15 seconds"}, 
   ImageSize -> {700, 500}}, 
 Inset[Framed[
   Grid[{{"Run 0"}, {"N=" Length[
        dataHist5] "/50"}, {"A=" seA}, {"t_{frac{1}{2}}=" PlusMinus[
        halfLife, 
        sehalfLife]}, {"\[Chi]^{2}=" fit[
         "ANOVATableSumsOfSquares"][[2]]}, {"Reduced \[Chi]^{2}=" fit[
         "ANOVATableMeanSquares"][[2]]}}], Background -> White, 
   RoundingRadius -> 5, Scaled[{.85, .9}]]]]
```

**Data:**

```
dataHist5 = {{Around[16.5, 1.5], 
   Around[77.8, 8.8]}, {Around[34.5, 1.5], 
   Around[60.5, 8.0]}, {Around[52.5, 1.5], 
   Around[63.8, 8.0]}, {Around[106.5, 1.5], 
   Around[42.4, 6.5]}, {Around[124.5, 1.5], 
   Around[41.7, 6.5]}, {Around[142.5, 1.5], 
   Around[14.6, 3.8]}, {Around[160.5, 1.5], 
   Around[33.9, 5.8]}, {Around[178.5, 1.5], 
   Around[29.4, 5.4]}, {Around[196.5, 1.5], 
   Around[33.5, 5.8]}, {Around[214.5, 1.5], 
   Around[30.9, 5.6]}, {Around[232.5, 1.5], 
   Around[31.1, 5.8]}, {Around[250.5, 1.5], 
   Around[21.5, 4.6]}, {Around[268.5, 1.5], 
   Around[4.3, 2.1]}, {Around[286.5, 1.5], 
   Around[6.4, 2.5]}, {Around[322.5, 1.5], 
   Around[7.5, 2.7]}, {Around[340.5, 1.5], 
   Around[4.5, 2.1]}, {Around[358.5, 1.5], 
   Around[11., 3.3]}, {Around[376.5, 1.5], 
   Around[14.0, 3.7]}, {Around[394.5, 1.5], 
   Around[14.0, 3.7]}, {Around[466.5, 1.5], 
   Around[0.6, 0.7]}, {Around[502.5, 1.5], 
   Around[2.2, 1.5]}, {Around[520.5, 1.5], 
   Around[9.4, 3.1]}, {Around[538.5, 1.5], 
   Around[4.1, 2.0]}, {Around[646.5, 1.5], 
   Around[2.2, 1.5]}, {Around[682.5, 1.5], Around[0.6, 0.7]}}
```

**Background:**

This is the results of a radioactive decay experiment. These are points obtained from gaussian models (which is why they aren't integer), then points are then plotted and a model applied (the model is y=Ae^-(kt)), and then weighted for the uncertainties (weighting is 1/uncertainty^2). The target is then to find A (this is the y-intercept), k (this is the decay constant and will give the half-life, t = ln(2) / k). Half-life being the main desired figured (the time is takes for the decay curve to have reduced by half). Then produces the reduced chi^2 as a measure of a goodness of fit. And express this on a singular graphic, much as m_goldberg has done below.

Re-creating m_goldberg's answer:

Having copied the code across - it errors. I have tried to implement what I thought were fixes but unsuccessfully. I changed `NonLinearModelfitData` to `NonLinearModel[fitData,...]`, And on the very last line the `Show` is not closed due to a missing speech mark after 'emission', so I added that in. But it outputs this:

[image]

Comment: What is the definition of `uncertainties`? Without it being defined, your fit doesn't work and no one can see what is wrong with the rest of your code.

Comment: `uncertainties = dataHist5[[All, 2, 2]];`
But in practical terms, it's the error bars around each of the data points in dataHist5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Edit 2

Well, I have thought more about your code and managed to get what looks like a reasonable fit.

Here is my 2nd revision of your code. I don't have any knowledge of the problem domain, so I can't be sure this is a satisfactory answer, but it looks more like what I think you want.

```
dataHist5 =
  {{Around[16.5, 1.5], Around[77.8, 8.8]}, 
   {Around[34.5, 1.5], Around[60.5, 8.0]},
   {Around[52.5, 1.5], Around[63.8, 8.0]}, 
   {Around[106.5, 1.5], Around[42.4, 6.5]},
   {Around[124.5, 1.5], Around[41.7, 6.5]}, 
   {Around[142.5, 1.5], Around[14.6, 3.8]},
   {Around[160.5, 1.5], Around[33.9, 5.8]}, 
   {Around[178.5, 1.5], Around[29.4, 5.4]},
   {Around[196.5, 1.5], Around[33.5, 5.8]}, 
   {Around[214.5, 1.5], Around[30.9, 5.6]},
   {Around[232.5, 1.5], Around[31.1, 5.8]}, 
   {Around[250.5, 1.5], Around[21.5, 4.6]},
   {Around[268.5, 1.5], Around[4.3, 2.1]}, 
   {Around[286.5, 1.5], Around[6.4, 2.5]},
   {Around[322.5, 1.5], Around[7.5, 2.7]}, 
   {Around[340.5, 1.5], Around[4.5, 2.1]},
   {Around[358.5, 1.5], Around[11., 3.3]}, 
   {Around[376.5, 1.5], Around[14.0, 3.7]},
   {Around[394.5, 1.5], Around[14.0, 3.7]}, 
   {Around[466.5, 1.5], Around[0.6, 0.7]},
   {Around[502.5, 1.5], Around[2.2, 1.5]}, 
   {Around[520.5, 1.5], Around[9.4, 3.1]},
   {Around[538.5, 1.5], Around[4.1, 2.0]}, 
   {Around[646.5, 1.5], Around[2.2, 1.5]},
   {Around[682.5, 1.5], Around[0.6, 0.7]}};
fitData = {#[[1, 1]], #[[2, 1]]} & /@ dataHist5;

Clear[A, k]
uncertainties = dataHist5[[All, 2, 2]];
fit =
  NonlinearModelFit[fitData, A Exp[-k t], {A, k}, t, Weights -> 1/uncertainties^2]
```

[image: fit]

```
{A, k} = {A, k} /. fit["BestFitParameters"];
{σA, σk} = fit["ParameterErrors"];
hLife = Log[2]/Around[k, σk];
seA = Around[A, σA];
halfLife = hLife[[1]];
sehalfLife = hLife[[2]];
```

Here is the combined plot:

```
Show[
  Plot[fit[x], {x, 0, 800},
    PlotRange -> All,
    PlotTheme -> "Detailed",
    PlotStyle -> Red,
    Axes -> False,
    Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
    FrameLabel -> {"Time /s", "Counts Recorded in the Previous 15 seconds"},
    ImageSize -> Large],
  ListPlot[dataHist5, ImageSize -> Large],
  Graphics[
    Inset[
      Framed[
        Column[
          {"Run 0",
           Row[{"N=" , Length[dataHist5], "/50"}],
           Row[{"A=" , seA}],
           Row[{Subscript[t, 1/2], "=" , PlusMinus[halfLife, sehalfLife]}],
           Row[{"χ^{2}=" , fit["ANOVATableSumsOfSquares"][[2]]}], 
           Row[{"Reduced χ^{2}=", fit["ANOVATableMeanSquares"][[2]]}]}],
        Background -> White,
        RoundingRadius -> 5],
      {Right, Top},
      Scaled[{1.1, 1.2}]]],
  PlotLabel ->
    Row[{"Decay Curve of Phosphorus-31 by ", Superscript[β, "+"], " Emission"}]]
```

[image: combined_plot]

The above code is a very careful cut and paste from the latest version of my Mathematica notebook in which I worked on your problem. I ran the code in Mathematica V12.1.1 running on MacOS 10.13.4.

Please copy and paste the code into a new, empty notebook, run it in a new Mathematica session and see if it still gives you errors.

Comment: Thank you, this has been a big help. I must've had so many errors in there by comparison. I wonder why my fitting for this set of data returns a different half life (Ln(2)/k) than when JimB did it in this question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/239832/applying-an-exponential-decay-fit-with-uncertainties - it's the same data and should be the same model. Thank you for helping fix the styling.

Comment: Hi. I tried to recreate this answer by copying the posted code, but it doesn't produce the attached graph, and I haven't managed to chase the error out. I believe there's 2, one I think is a square bracket missing in 'NonLinearModelfitData' to be 'NonLinearModel[fitData,...]. I'm not sure about the other, I think it's another bracket somewhere in the plot code

Comment: Added the background as mentioned and my attempt to recreate the graph

Comment: @Epideme There was an error in the `Show` code, a missing end quote in the `PlotLabel` option. I have fixed it.

Comment: Yeh I thought it was that, but it doesn't seem to be working. I think the NonLinearModelfitData needs a square bracket, but I've tried adding that in too. I've put the graph I get out in the question but i will have another go in the morning. thank you.

Comment: I did try to run it again, and it still errors. I've included in the question, at the bottom, what it shows the errors to be and the graph produced

Comment: Okay, got to the bottom of it...
The `fit = NonLinear...` line should read
`fit = NonlinearModelFit[fitData, A Exp[-k t], {A, k}, t, 
  Weights -> 1/uncertainties^2]`

Would it be possible to update this in the answer, and then I can mark it off as the accepted answer. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Epideme. I have pasted a new copy of my code into the answer. It works exactly as it I expect it to on my system. Please try it on yours in a new notebook in a new Mathematica sessaion.

Comment: All working correct. We got there in the end, thank you for the help!