# Graph Plotting Error - NonLinearModel and 'neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table'

Tags: plotting, graphics, error-tracking

I am trying to produce a nice looking graph from Mathematica. (if any background on that is required, I am happy to share, but I'll keep it short for now unless anyone is interested)

**Question:**

Question is, quite simply, why am I unable to recreate another user's answer when they very kindly helped put together the code for me. It uses the same code but we get different results.

**Code:**

```
dataHist5 =
  {{Around[16.5, 1.5], Around[77.8, 8.8]}, 
   {Around[34.5, 1.5], Around[60.5, 8.0]}, 
   {Around[52.5, 1.5], Around[63.8, 8.0]}, 
   {Around[106.5, 1.5], Around[42.4, 6.5]}, 
   {Around[124.5, 1.5], Around[41.7, 6.5]}, 
   {Around[142.5, 1.5], Around[14.6, 3.8]}, 
   {Around[160.5, 1.5], Around[33.9, 5.8]}, 
   {Around[178.5, 1.5], Around[29.4, 5.4]}, 
   {Around[196.5, 1.5], Around[33.5, 5.8]}, 
   {Around[214.5, 1.5], Around[30.9, 5.6]}, 
   {Around[232.5, 1.5], Around[31.1, 5.8]}, 
   {Around[250.5, 1.5], Around[21.5, 4.6]}, 
   {Around[268.5, 1.5], Around[4.3, 2.1]}, 
   {Around[286.5, 1.5], Around[6.4, 2.5]}, 
   {Around[322.5, 1.5], Around[7.5, 2.7]}, 
   {Around[340.5, 1.5], Around[4.5, 2.1]}, 
   {Around[358.5, 1.5], Around[11., 3.3]}, 
   {Around[376.5, 1.5], Around[14.0, 3.7]}, 
   {Around[394.5, 1.5], Around[14.0, 3.7]}, 
   {Around[466.5, 1.5], Around[0.6, 0.7]}, 
   {Around[502.5, 1.5], Around[2.2, 1.5]}, 
   {Around[520.5, 1.5], Around[9.4, 3.1]}, 
   {Around[538.5, 1.5], Around[4.1, 2.0]}, 
   {Around[646.5, 1.5], Around[2.2, 1.5]}, 
   {Around[682.5, 1.5], Around[0.6, 0.7]}};
fitData = {#[[1, 1]], #[[2, 1]]} & /@ dataHist5;

Clear[A, k]
uncertainties = dataHist5[[All, 2, 2]];
fit =
  NonlinearModelfitData, A Exp[-k t], {A, k}, t, Weights -> 1/uncertainties^2]

{A, k} = {A, k} /. fit["BestFitParameters"];
{σA, σk} = fit["ParameterErrors"];
hLife = Log[2]/Around[k, σk];
halfLife = hLife[[1]];
seA = Around[A, σA];
sehalfLife = hLife[[2]];

Show[
  Plot[fit[x], {x, 0, 800},
    PlotRange -> All,
    PlotTheme -> "Detailed",
    PlotStyle -> Red,
    Axes -> False,
    Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
    FrameLabel -> {"Time /s", "Counts Recorded in the Previous 15 seconds"},
    ImageSize -> Large],
  ListPlot[dataHist5, ImageSize -> Large],
  Graphics[
    Inset[
      Framed[
        Column[
          {"Run 0",
           Row[{"N=" , Length[dataHist5], "/50"}],
           Row[{"A=" , seA}],
           Row[{Subscript[t, 1/2], "=" , PlusMinus[halfLife, sehalfLife]}],
           Row[{"χ^{2}=", fit["ANOVATableSumsOfSquares"][[2]]}], 
           Row[{"Reduced χ^{2}=", fit["ANOVATableMeanSquares"][[2]]}]}],
        Background -> White,
        RoundingRadius -> 5],
      {Right, Top},
      Scaled[{1.1, 1.2}]]],
  PlotLabel -> "Decay Curve of Phosphorus-31 by β^{+} Emission"]
```

**Output:**

Expected Output from the other user's answer:
[image: Expected Output]

My Output from the same code:
[image: Observed Output]

**Attempts:**

I think there may be an error in the `NonlinearModelfitData` line, where it should be `NonlinearModel[fitData...`, so I have replaced this. However it still only produces the graph above, not the expected one. The other answers I've read don't hugely seem to apply here, but I think the problem might be in the defining of `fitData` line.

**Link:**
Comes initially from [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/241128/plot-styling-errors-plotlabel-plottheme-inset-not-appearing) question.

Comment: Please try: NonlinearModelFit[fitData, A Exp[-k t], {A, k}, t, 
 Weights -> 1/uncertainties^2]

Comment: What should `fit =
  NonlinearModelfitData, A Exp[-k t], {A, k}, t, Weights -> 1/uncertainties^2]` mean?

Comment: `NonlinearModelFit[fitData, A Exp[-k t], {A, k}, t, Weights -> 1/uncertainties^2] ` has fixed it perfectly. Thank you very much to both of you.

Comment: Up to you guys, if you'd like to write it as an answer and i'll accept it for future people who are searching for this

Comment: If you delete the inset, you get what you expect and in addition some error messages. Therefore look at the insert, there are some errors.

Comment: The error was the one demm suggested I think as that correction seems to have cleared it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
NonlinearModelFit[fitData, A Exp[-k t], {A, k}, t, Weights -> 1/uncertainties^2]
```